# Will this create any leak?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-leaks, nsarray

I have array containing objects of type Store in mutableCopy. I release array, do I release all objects before releasing the array?

```
NSMutableArray *stores=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[stores addObject:[store1 mutableCopy]];
[stores addObject:[store2 mutableCopy]];
[stores addObject:[store3 mutableCopy]];
...
[stores release];
```

Comment: Autorelease them as sugested. addObject will retain them and removeObject or removeAllObjects will release them. If you do not autorelease them then you can release the array objects right before releasing the array stores. However, autorelease is smarter and safer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't use ARC, then you need to release your objects at some point, since the `- mutableCopy` method creates a new object with a retain count of +1. To avoid leaks, you should write:

```
[stores addObject:[[store1 mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

Now, there is no reason not to use ARC. If you use ARC, you're fine and you don't call `- release` on anything.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

You should use:

```
[stores addObject:[[store1 mutableCopy] autorelease]];
```

Comment: And even better would be to use ARC.